# System.IO.IOException: The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Construi uma aplicação usando asp.net onde em alguns momentos da aplicação eu preciso acessar um diretório e fazer a verificação de arquivos e algumas vezes mover e apagar eles. No meu micro funcionou perfeitamente, porém ao subir a aplicação no servidor IIS o mesmo começou a retornar o erro **System.IO.IOException: The user name or password is incorrect.**. Acessei o servidor e loguei no diretório que preciso acessar, além disso dei permissão para o usuário IUSR (aliás para todos), conseguirem acessar, porém continuo recebendo a mensagem de erro. Existe alguma forma de logar dentro da aplicação no diretório passando usuário e senha ou conseguir acessar o diretório de alguma outra forma?

Obs.: O micro que estou tentando acessar não está no mesmo domínio que meu servidor e infelizmente não posso coloca-los no mesmo domínio.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você tem uma aplicação no servidor x que tenta acessar um diretório no servidor y. É isso?

Comment: Sim. Um servidor enxerga o outro, apenas dentro da aplicação não está funcionando.

Comment: Cara, como está conectando ou outro micro? FTP? Show me the code!

Comment: aparentemente, você está tentando acessar uma pasta de um servidor que exige logon. Ao iniciar o serviço no IIS, ele tenta acessar com a credencial do IUSR, que não será validada no outro servidor. Achei algo que parece solucionar: Não sei se vai funcionar para asp.net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023607/how-to-use-logonuser-properly-to-impersonate-domain-user-from-workgroup-client

Comment: Localmente não precisei logar usando a aplicação. Eu loguei no próprio windows. Na minha aplicação eu estou basicamente executando `Directory.GetFiles();` e funciona normalmente. Já no server não rola. No inicio pensei que pudesse ser algo no windows. Mas o que eu fiz localmente não rolou no server.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis vou tentar implementar esse código e posto o resultado.

Comment: você também pode utilizar uma unidade de rede mapeada. Já tentou ? pode ser mais fácil

Comment: Tentei utilizar a unidade mapeada, novamente localmente funcionou perfeitamente. Já no servidor não rolou. Apenas me retorna dizendo que o caminho não foi encontrado.

Comment: utiliza o prompt de comando como administrador para mapear a unidade

Comment: Coloca o código de como você está fazendo para acessar esse diretório

Comment: a principio consegui fazer com uma "gambiarra". Criei um usuário no meu servidor de aplicação e outro no servidor de destino com o mesmo nome de usuário e senha. Assim o sistema conseguiu acessar e manipular os arquivos.

Answer (score 1):

Boa Noite,

Tenta com o seguinte pedaço de código:

```
using (var networkCon = new NetworkConnection(destinationFolder, New NetworkCredential(username, password))
{
    File.ReadAllText(destinationFolder + "Teste.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque o nome de usuário em que o app esta rodando na máquina de produção não possui acesso no outro servidor, dando exception.

Provavelmente rodou localmente porque o usuário que esta rodando a máquina local tem acesso a este servidor remoto, não dando erro.

Comment: A segurança da pasta que estou tentando acessar está configurada para **todos**.

Comment: Ja viu o Application pool identity ?

Comment: Sim, troquei por um usuário com mais privilégios e mesmo assim não rolou.

Comment: colocou permissao no diretorio tipo esse cara faz nesse tutorial? https://docs.litium.com/more/best-practices/tips-tricks/give-directory-access-permission-to-iis-application-pool

Comment: teste tb <identity impersonate="true" /> no seu webconfig

Comment: Mesmo que a segurança da pasta no outro servidor estando como permissão para Todos, o servidor exige autenticação ao tentar acessar as pastas compartilhadas. Aí que o problema acontece.